# Is ShiftRows(SubtBytes(x)) = SubtBytes(ShiftRows(x)) the same for the same entry : in AES

Tags: aes, symmetric, s-boxes

Is `ShiftRows(SubtBytes(x)) = SubtBytes(ShiftRows(x))` the same for the same entry : in AES

It seems like these two are equal, can someone explain in theoretically?

Comment: Is the same because the s-box values of row and col doesn't depend on the matrix row and col but its value...

Comment: have you heard about super-box? . you might find your answer in this link: https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/531.pdf

Answer (score 5):

There is no theoretically required here.

ShiftRows changes the position of bytes, regardless of their value

SubBytes changes the value of bytes, regardless of their position

Therefore the order of these operations does not matter